# Actionbar set the home button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-custom-view

I am using a `NavigationDrawer` with my `ActionBar`. It needs the home button and configured as up.

I try to put a button in the middle of the action. The only way I found is to use a custom layout.

But when I use it, my home title is erased. Even if it has the space to be displayed.
Is there a way to set the home button to always show his title ?

If not is there an other trick ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you using ActionBarSherock ?

Comment: Arf no it does not work too :/

Answer (score 1):

actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

and add

```
// For back Button
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {       
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:         
      Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, DashbordActivity.class);
      homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      startActivity(homeIntent);
    }
  return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try following code

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```